# /dev/urandom maximum size

Tags: unix

If you want to read N bytes guaranteed from /dev/urandom, is it safe to perform a single read call and be guaranteed you get N bytes - or are there some operating systems that don't provide that guarantee, and may produce a short read from /dev/urandom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A read from `/dev/urandom` may return before being fully satisfied if interrupted by a signal.

Answer (score 2):

To be safe, I would not assume that full reads are guaranteed, and instead read repeatedly until you have as much data as you need. You never know when some implementation is going to decide that short reads from `/dev/urandom` are fine.

Comment: The code in question (os.py:urandom) is doing exactly that right now, and it led to an application hang on a misconfigured system (see http://bugs.python.org/issue10824). If a properly-configured system would provide the guaranteed I'm asking for, it would help in reliably detecing misconfigured systems.

Comment: As mentioned in that issue, it might be worth at some point doing a check to see whether `/dev/urandom` is a regular file or not. Perhaps during Python installation, but maybe not every time `os.urandom()` is called. I'm rather inclined to agree that "misconfigured system" implies "undefined behaviour".

Comment: Still: I'd prefer to have some kind of answer to my question, e.g. in the form "I know for sure that these five systems meet these urandom expectations" - or (perhaps even better): "I know for sure that XYZ has short reads from /dev/urandom".

Comment: @Martin: It really is best to assume that any read may be short, regardless of the file/device/socket/pipe you're reading from (excluding datagrams, of course)

Comment: @Hasturkun: why could the read be short? Can you demonstrate that for /dev/urandom on some system?

Comment: @Martin: for `/dev/urandom` it's incredibly unlikely, but still not impossible. the only guarantee I see for urandom is that it will not block waiting for more entropy. this still doesn't mean that the read will be fully satisfied

Comment: @Hasturkun: so why could it not be satisfied, and on what system?

Comment: @Martin: It could happen if the read is interrupted by a signal.

Comment: @Hasturkun: I see. Post that as an answer, and I'll accept it.